# How to make my client wait for the server to update some SyncVar data using Mirror in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, synchronization, mirror

I am developing a tank game where the tanks move around the tilemap randomly (they are not controlled by any player). What I am trying to do is that each time the tank asks the server what is in the next cell he wants to move to. The server will write on a SyncVar if the next tile is empty or if it has any obstacle. The client should wait for the answer instead of keeping executing the following lines.

I have tried using a loop with a condition until the data is updated but it obviously crashes the game.

I couldn't find anything else and I am not very familiarised with C#.

```
//Definition of syncvar
[SyncVar]
private bool tilebase_rec;

//Command for the server
[Command]
void Cmdserver_GetTile(Vector3Int testCell){
   Tilemap tilemap = GameObject.Find("Obstacles2").GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        
   TileBase tile = tilemap.GetTile(testCell);
        
   tilebase_rec = tile == roadTile;
}

//What I use on the client
bool tile = tilebase_rec;
```